# Jars required to create a spring web service project

Tags: java, spring, web-services, maven, spring-mvc

Could someone give me list of jars required to create spring web service project?

I visited both [MVN Repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.ws) and [Spring Web Site](http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/) but did not understand which are manadatory jars to create a spring-ws project.

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-ws/

Comment: What's unclear in "The recommended way to get started using spring-ws in your project is with a dependency management system – the snippet below can be copied and pasted into your build. Need help? See our getting started guides on building with Maven and Gradle."?

Comment: you mean to say only spring-ws.jar and no need of spring-ws-core.jar, spring-ws-security.jar, spring-ws-support.jar, etc listed in MVN repo.

Comment: What's unclear in "The recommended way - It is guide to create maven project & not specify which jars required for spring web services.

Comment: The recommended way is to let the build tool get the required jars automatically. That's the whole point of dependency management. Learn to use Gradle (or Maven), and it will get all the required jars for you, automatically.

Comment: I have created Hello World maven project. When trying to run in eclipse it is asking for goal. What should i give in goal can u tell me ?

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: thanks all for replying. i m trying to understand maven build tool.

Comment: [Spring-WEB](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-modules) and required [maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) [JAR's](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework)